# Object values to Enum or type

Tags: typescript

I have a object as :

```
const bodyParts: Record<string, string>  = {
  HAND: 'hand',
  MOUTH: 'mouth'
}
```

I have used the object later as

```
type PartType = "hand"| "mouth"

const data: Array<{part: 'hand' | 'mouth'}> = [{
  part: bodyParts[HAND]
}, {
  part: bodyParts[MOUTH]
}
]
```

But I want to extract `PartType` from values of `bodyParts`. Is there any walkaround for this?
Or maybe to create enum from object and set type as enum. I tried looking for creating enum but didnot got to solution.
I can create Enum but I want to automate task of creation of enum, as bodyparts can be added.

Comment: Why not have `BodyParts` as enum?

Comment: What is the use case for `bodyParts` and for `data`? This seems like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...

Comment: I can create `BodyParts` as enum, but I want to automate this process. If I add bodypart, I should update enum as well.
I just want to update bodyPart and everything to be updated itself.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect with a broader understanding of your end goal, one could suggest a better alternative to the use of `bodyParts` as shown in the question, but you *can* do what you want to do by inferring the type from the constant, like this:

```typescript
const bodyParts: Record<string, string> = {
    HAND: "hand",
    MOUTH: "mouth",
};

const data: Array<{ part: typeof bodyParts[keyof typeof bodyParts] }> = [
    {
        part: bodyParts.HAND,
    },
    {
        part: bodyParts.MOUTH,
    },
];
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARiAJgTwAoEMBOUIC4YBKApqJogDzSYCWYA5gDQxW10B8MAvDAN4BQMQTAASAQQByAEXwAiABbowiGQwFCAsgHkAqgBVhsgLYgArlDkq+AXwDcfPqEixE6KOnyjMmdMnI8YAA5YUPhQyAFEIABm8EhowRAA2gDWRMjRMGERGQgoGNgQALowVhzciWqC-EI1gcH4ufEFAHRiUqo1Vh1C1bWCQdgNcfk4zVp6wt2CXXyFNkA)

Or it's a bit clearer if we grab an alias for `typeof bodyParts`:

```typescript
const bodyParts: Record<string, string> = {
    HAND: "hand",
    MOUTH: "mouth",
};
type BodyParts = typeof bodyParts;

const data: Array<{ part: BodyParts[keyof BodyParts] }> = [
    {
        part: bodyParts.HAND,
    },
    {
        part: bodyParts.MOUTH,
    },
];
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARiAJgTwAoEMBOUIC4YBKApqJogDzSYCWYA5gDQxW10B8MAvDAN4BQMQTAASAQQByAEXwAiABbowiGQwFCAsgHkAqgBVhsgLYgArlDkq+AXwDcfKMgAORGACEkaLDi4wHzkABm8B4Y2BB2fKCQsIjoUOj4opiY6MjkPDCOXvjuKKE4ANoA1kTIgW4hXhAAujBWHNwFaoL8Qm2Z2cF5VQB0YlKqbVaDQq3tglnY+AjdYT1aesIjgsN81TZAA)

**But**, if you want to preserve the compile-time type of those (and in particular to ensure that `data` is a tuple, not just an array), you may do better with `const` assertions and less explicit typing:

```typescript
const bodyParts = {
    HAND: "hand",
    MOUTH: "mouth",
} as const;

const data = [
    {
        part: bodyParts.HAND,
    },
    {
        part: bodyParts.MOUTH,
    },
] as const;
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARiAJgTwAoEMBOUIwLwwDeAUDGTABICCAcgCIBcMARABbpiLMA0p5AsgHkAqgBUKTZgFsQAVyisexAL4x0uUJCgBuYsU3QYidFHT4YAbT5kS5OzAAOWKEwQoM2CADpq9XneV-clt7MidsVyQ0Z28hMQogskDiAF01DXBobSA)